# Generic (non-file) pattern matching in Makefile

Tags: makefile, design-patterns

Is it possible to have wildcard targets for non-filenames, like:

```
build-%: pull-% build-%.stamp
pull-%:
  cd $* ; git log HEAD..origin/master | grep -q . && ( git pull ; $(RM) ../build-$*.stamp ) || true
build-%.stamp:
  cd $* ; ant
  touch $@
```

The idea is to call `make build-foo`, which will only call the build when there are new upstream changes (which get pulled).

However, the `%`-pattern matching appears to apply to filenames only, even when defining the expanded form ("build-foo") in .PHONY.

Do I have to use templates, as used in [Makefile generic pattern rule -- xyzzy-en_US.ext2 from xyzzy.ext0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064403) ?

Comment: This seems to work well enough in GNUMake 3.81. What Make are you using?

Comment: the same, GNU Make 3.81. Using the Makefile just like above `make build-foo` results in `make: *** No rule to make target `build-foo'.  Stop.` - not "well enough" for me.
I've used the TEMPLATE approach now, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Put a semicolon after the `build-%` rule.

(I didn't notice this problem because I put a command in the rule: `@echo $@`.)